# My ram is ( Hynix ) Company As Labelled in Photo . But in Cpu-Z indicates Model Manufacturer (Kingston ). Why Cpu-z Showing other Manufacturer Name?

Tags: memory

I Purchased 8 Gb DDR3 PC3L ram of ( Hynix ) Company on 7 July 2023 as Labelled in Photo [Hynix DDR3 RAM 8GB 2RX8 PC3L-12800U-11-11-F3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXC8U.jpg) But when I checked by CPU-Z. Here CPU-Z Indicates Model Kingston) Why CPU-Z Shows other Manufacturer Name Kingston instead original Hynix whereas all chips are marked with name Hynix.
[CPU-Z Detail about Hynix DDR3 RAM 8GB 2RX8 PC3L-12800U HMT451U6MFR8C-PB NO AA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D3cU.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

#### Hynix makes RAM for Kingston

Kingston purchases DRAM chips directly from manufacturers, which include Micron, **SK Hynix**, Powerchip, and Nanya.

Source: [Kingston DRAM Suppliers](https://www.kingston.com/en/company/why-choose-kingston#:%7E:text=DRAM%20Suppliers,%2C%20Powerchip%2C%20Nanya%20and%20others)

Hynix branded RAM is well regarded so it may be the case that the RAM you purchased had better resale value as "Hynix RAM" as opposed to "Kingston RAM (Hynix)"

Please note manufacture date per CPU-Z is 2019